# Resource Access by Parallel Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have 2 threads to are triggered at the same time and run in parallel. These 2 threads are going to be manipulating a string value, but I want to make sure that there are no data inconsistencies. For that I want to use a lock with `Monitor.Pulse` and `Monitor.Wait`. I used a method that I found on another question/answer, but whenever I run my program, the first thread gets stuck at the `Monitor.Wait` level. I think that's because the second thread has already "Pulsed" and "Waited". Here is some code to look at:

```
string currentInstruction;

public void nextInstruction() 
{
    Action actions = {
        fetch,
        decode
    }
    Parallel.Invoke(actions);
    _pc++;
}

public void fetch()
{
    lock(irLock) 
    {
        currentInstruction = "blah";
        GiveTurnTo(2);
        WaitTurn(1);
    }

    decodeEvent.WaitOne();
}

public void decode()
{
    decodeEvent.Set();

    lock(irLock) 
    {
        WaitTurn(2);
        currentInstruction = "decoding..."
        GiveTurnTo(1);
    }
}

// Below are the methods I talked about before.

// Wait for turn to use lock object
public static void WaitTurn(int threadNum, object _lock)
{
    // While( not this threads turn )
    while (threadInControl != threadNum)
    {
        // "Let go" of lock on SyncRoot and wait utill 
        // someone finishes their turn with it
        Monitor.Wait(_lock);
    }
}

// Pass turn over to other thread
public static void GiveTurnTo(int nextThreadNum, object _lock)
{
    threadInControl = nextThreadNum;
    // Notify waiting threads that it's someone else's turn
    Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
}
```

Any idea how to get 2 parallel threads to communicate (manipulate the same resources) within the same cycle using locks or anything else?

Comment: You invoke fetch and decode in parallel, but lock both of them so only one can execute at any given time. You should think about your program for a bit, there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run 2 peaces of code in parallel, but locking them at start using the same variable?

As nvoigt mentioned, it already sounds wrong. What you have to do is to remove `lock` from there. Use it only when you are about to access something exclusively.

Btw "data inconsistencies" can be avoided by not having to have them. Do not use `currentInstruction` field directly (is it a field?), but provide a thread safe `CurrentInstruction` property.

```
private object _currentInstructionLock = new object();
private string _currentInstruction
public string CurrentInstruction
{
    get { return _currentInstruction; }
    set
    {
        lock(_currentInstructionLock)
            _currentInstruction = value;
    }
}
```

Other thing is naming, local variables name starting from `_` is a bad style. Some peoples (incl. me) using them to distinguish private fields. Property name should start from BigLetter and local variables fromSmall.

Comment: Thanks. I threw this together really quick from what I understood about locks, but was lost when it didn't work. I'm using wait handles in each of my methods. Do you think I could manipulate those to benefit what I'm trying to achieve? I'll edit my question to reflect what I mean.